# How do I get Google Hangouts to remember my audio settings?

Tags: audio, google-hangouts

I have a variety of audio devices attached to my computer in addition to the built in speakers and microphone. When I use Google hangouts, I have to go to the configuration settings every time to tell it that I want to use my wireless headset (mic and speakers, respectively). This device is *always* attached to my computer, I have yet to enter a hangout without it attached and turned on.

I didn't have to configure audio settings each time in the recent past, hangouts would just use whatever device I used last, but now it's always defaulting to the on board hardware. Is there some different place or way that I can tell hangouts to remember my preferred device and just use it if available?

I use Chrome (latest stable) for hangouts, and allow all cookies / local storage to persist when the browser restarts. Do I really need to configure my audio settings *every* time I join a hangout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Chrome extension for Hangouts.  I use this on 4 different machines and it always remembers the individual settings for each machine.

[Google Hangouts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)